# Why do tetrahedral number appear when summing the diagonals of the multiplication chart?

Tags: number-theory

> Why do [tetrahedral numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedral_number) appear when summing the diagonals of the multiplication chart?

For example, $1$, $2+2$, $3+4+3$, $4+6+6+4$, etc., are all tetrahedral numbers.

Comment: So you are looking at sums like $$\sum_{k=1}^n k(n+1-k)?$$ Do you know how to evaluate such things?

Comment: Yes, actually this is one of the formula that may help.

Comment: Yes, but how can I relate this formula to my problem?

Comment: Old, one-minute long video that might help you visualize why: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mMW1B_OVuWI

Comment: Thanks, I’m going to watch it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

I think I have an answer to my question. It is very easy with the given formulas.